# Template: One page homework report (defaults have too much whitespace)

Tags: templates

I have been using latex for abut four months now but by all means I am a total nube.

I was wondering if anyone had a template for homework (specifically a one page report).
My teacher is pretty anal about the report being *just one page* and
I am finding that the article class has too much white-space.

Does anyone have a template they would like to share?

---

One thing I did to reduce the white space was:

```
\newenvironment{mynum}{
\begin{enumerate}
  \setlength{\itemsep}{1pt}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
}{\end{enumerate}}
```

Other things that take up unproportionate amounts of whitespace include:

- the title made by `\maketitle`
- headings made by `\section`
- narrow margins

Comment: Two small comments: (a) I assume you already know about the `fullpage` package? (b) Honestly, I can't see why you need to section a one-page report.

Comment: @Willie, I like to add headings to my work.  I find that this improves readability.  For example: purpose, approach, findings, conclusions, one paragraph for each.

Comment: Since you are constrained to 1 page anyway, there's not much point in using `\ref` and `\label` pairs to refer to the headings; and you won't be using a TOC, will it be agreeable to just fake it with `\noindent \textbf{Heading.}` It is not the semantically correct sol'n, but will probably save you some trouble.

Answer (score 4):

The savetrees package uses lots of tricks like these to cram as much material as possible into a page. Not typographically great, but sounds like something you might like.

Answer (score 4):

Multiple columns with [multicol](http://tug.ctan.org/cgi-bin/ctanPackageInformation.py?id=multicol)

Less spacing between `itemize` bullets with [mdwlist](http://tug.ctan.org/cgi-bin/ctanPackageInformation.py?id=mdwlist) (using `itemize*` )

Shrinking section headings with `\usepackage[medium,compact]{titlesec}` (or `[small,compact]` if you're hardcore) [Titlesec](http://tug.ctan.org/cgi-bin/ctanPackageInformation.py?id=titlesec)

And someone's already mentioned `savetrees`

And the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/674/squeezing-scientific-paper-to-fit-within-page-limits) are super relevant.

Answer (score 3):

The `fullpage` package gives you margins which are smaller than the normal margins and resembles the margins most WYSIWYG systems give you as default.

Answer (score 0):

Try some awesome homework templates by Ted Pavlic (I had to modify them for my purposes).

http://www.tedpavlic.com/post_homework_tex_example.php