# Fit given text on a user specified number of pages

Tags: margins, fontsize, fit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any  package to automatically select font size and margins to optimize pages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19347/is-there-any-package-to-automatically-select-font-size-and-margins-to-optimize)

Is it possible to make a given text fit on *n* pages, where *n* is a number chosen by the user?

Preferably by diminishing the margins first (up to a certain point). Changing the fontsize is acceptable too but only after the margins have their minimum values.

The document is plain text. There are no figures, tables or other float like environments. Just plain text with sections and subsections + enumerate and itemize environments. No footnotes either.

Can something like this be achieved through TeX? Or I should use an external script (recompiiling at every circle?)?

Comment: This question on [fitting text into a given box by adjusting the fontsize](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26002/fit-text-into-given-box-by-adjusting-the-fontsize) might be a useful starting point.

Comment: @pmav99 Please see my comments on the link provided by Peter Grill. When you carry out such optimizations, you need to define your constraints more clearly, for example, you can reduce whitespace around figures and headings and you can scale figures. You can reduce tolerances between footnotes and text etc... Perhaps if you explain in more detail why you want to achieve this.

Comment: Also see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19347/is-there-any-package-to-automatically-select-font-size-and-margins-to-optimize-p, which covers similar concepts.