# Minimize automatically the page size of the PDF outputs

Tags: pdf, margins

I would like to produce the PDF version of the following TEX code without margins. How can I achieve this automaticcaly, even if it needs tricky code (I'm a regular user of Python) ?

I would like to that so as to show examples of small LaTeX codes without wasting storing spaces on my web site.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{ucs}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{amssymb}


\begin{document}

\section{One document to display}

How to produce an output without any margin.

\noindent
$ E = m c^2 $ but it seems that we can have $ v > c $.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you asking about a small page/paper size or about small file size? (I don't think getting rid of margins will have a huge impact on file size.) In either case, this question is likely to be a duplicate; in case of the former, take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/674/squeezing-scientific-paper-to-fit-within-page-limits, in case of the latter http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2198/how-to-create-small-final-pdf-files-for-the-internet and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18987/how-to-make-the-pdfs-produced-by-pdflatex-smaller.

Comment: Flag as duplicate of [How can I create a pdf document exactly as big as my tikz picture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/452/how-can-i-create-a-pdf-document-exactly-as-big-as-my-tikz-picture) (technically not a duplicate, but every answer to this question can also be posted to the other question)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I would recommend you use [the `varwidth` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/varwidth) which is similar to the `minipage` environment, but sets its width to match the *narrower natural width* based on the content.

This can be used either with [the `standalone` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/standalone), or you can directly use [the `preview` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/preview) to get (note that the border shown here is from my image capturing):

[image]

Here is the MWE using the `standalone` class:

```
\documentclass[tightpage]{standalone}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\begin{document}
\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
\section{One document to display}

How to produce an output without any margin.

\par\noindent
$ E = m c^2 $ but it seems that we can have $ v > c $.
\end{varwidth}
\end{document}
```

and using the `preview` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
\section{One document to display}

How to produce an output without any margin.

\par\noindent
$ E = m c^2 $ but it seems that we can have $ v > c $.
\end{varwidth}
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

I suspect that `standalone` class internally uses the `preview` package to do something like this, so probably not much difference in this case, but might be useful if you needed to use a different class.

---

If this is something you are going to do often it is worthwhile automating this solution by using `\AtBeginDocument` and `\AtEndDocument` in the preamble to automate this. Here is  the same code with this automation in the preamble and using the `book` class:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\AtBeginDocument{\begin{preview}\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}}
\AtEndDocument{\end{varwidth}\end{preview}}

\begin{document}
\section{One document to display}

How to produce an output without any margin.

\par\noindent
$ E = m c^2 $ but it seems that we can have $ v > c $.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I didn't know about the `varwidth` package until I saw your answer. Great stuff!

Answer (score 13):

You could configure your document to have no margins, for example by [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package commands or using the [`standalone`](http://ctan.org/pkg/standalone) class, as Mico already suggested.

However if you need class features and cannot use `standalone`, or if you don't like to change the document, but to crop the margins from the PDF output, you could use the [`pdfcrop`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfcrop) script which can automatically crop the white margins. Here it would be useful to configure `empty` page style for removing the page numbering as well.

Answer (score 10):

Use the `standalone` rather than the `article` document class. Among other things, it will crop rather tightly the output of your (pdf)latex run. E.g., the following modification of your example code (I've mainly stripped out some unneeded `\usepackage` instructions),

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\section{One document to display}
How to produce output without any margin.

\noindent
$ E = m c^2 $ but it seems that we can have $ v > c $.
\end{document}
```

will produce the following output (one can't see that the image is cropped tightly, so you'll have to take my word for it):

[image]

**Addendum:** If you want to restrict the width of the pdf file produced with the document class set as `standalone`, say to the width of a known string of text, you can do so by using the `\settowidth` command in the preamble. In the example you provided, the relevant string is the content of the section header -- the numeral 1, a space (of width `\quad`), and the string "One document to display", all set in bold in the font size `\Large`. Hence, you'd type

```
\settowidth{\textwidth}{\Large\textbf{1\quad One document to display}}
```

to set the `\textwidth` macro.

Obviously, the macro `\textwidth` should be set to the width of the single longest string of text you anticipate having. I recommend you first comment out the `\settowidth` instruction in the preamble, optimize the document to your liking, then figure out what the longest string is, and finally make that string the second argument of the `\settowidth` command. Happy TeXing!

Comment: Hello. The problem with the `standalone` package is that there is still an unusefull margin at the right...

Comment: I've provided an addendum to show how one can restrict the width of the pdf file, using the command `\settowidth`.

Comment: Thanks for this amelioration but I would like an automatic solution because all the PDF ouptuts will be generated automatically...

Comment: The extra space at the right is caused by the paragraph break which creates a full box `\textwidth` wide. Simply using `\mbox{}` around it to avoid a paragraph should work. Also a `minipage` with a given width should do it.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: Umm, may I ask you to be a bit more specific with regard to "simply using `\mbox{}` around it"? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Mico: Sorry, that seems not to work like I thought for text+math like shown. However, I might extend `standalone` to support such cases better.

Comment: Mico, thanks for the tip. The `\settowidth` worked when nothing else did. @MartinScharrer: Is this the best one can do when using the standalone package?

Comment: @FaheemMitha: Try the `varwidth` option which got added with v1.0.