# How to compile pseudocode into pdf without margins?

Tags: algorithms

I want to compile a pseudocode for an algorithm into a separate pdf and then include it into my main document as a figure. However, the compiled pseudocode gets compiled into a pdf with margins and I have not been able to crop it (other than manually) to fit into a tighter box. I used `pdfcrop` to try to get rid of the white space, but it only removes white space at the top, left, and right, but not the bottom. I would like to be able to compile it so that it has no margins and not to have to do it manually every time I change a comma in the pseudocode.
Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\begin{document}
  \begin{algorithm}[h!]
    \begin{algorithmic}
    \caption{Precomputing densities}
    \label{alg:densities}
      \FOR{$i = 1 \to n$}
        \STATE $\mathrm{sums}[i][i] \gets 0$
      \ENDFOR
    \end{algorithmic}
  \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Any advice?

Comment: Does [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32773/minimize-automatically-the-page-size-of-the-pdf-outputs) help?

Comment: Tried using preview: produces an "Undefined control sequence." on the line with \begin{algorithm}.

Comment: Your trimming via [`pdfcrop`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfcrop) probably includes the page number. Use `\pagestyle{empty}` for such stand-alone instances.

Comment: That's it - removing the page number allows pdfcrop to crop it properly! Thanks a lot!

Comment: My hunch was to instead use the document class `standalone` but when I try it I get "LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode."

Comment: yes - I tried that too and apparently standalone does not approve of algorithm environment inside the doc

Comment: I think it's due to the `algorithm` environment being a float, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33566/how-to-compile-pseudocode-into-pdf-without-margins

Comment: Yup. If you take it out of the `algorithm` environment you can compile it. You lose the caption though.

Comment: @N.N.: Your link takes me back to this question. Which question are you referring to?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you tried this with

```
\pagestyle{emtpy}
```

just below `\begin{document}`? This may get rid of something in the footer that pdfcrop is having trouble with.

Comment: It worked - removed the page number and pdfcrop cropped it alright. Thanks!

Comment: That was my first ever post! You're very welcome. Glad I could help.