# Scaling a PDF page to fit a logic puzzle

Tags: pdftex, standalone, varwidth, logicpuzzle, scale

I am trying to create a big logic puzzle using the `logicpuzzle` package. I want the resulting PDF page to fit the whole logic puzzle. I have tried using the `standalone` document class, but the puzzle is cut off in the PDF.

Here is an example of what I have tried so far:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{logicpuzzle}

\begin{document}
  \begin{fourwinds}[rows=50,columns=50,scale=0.5]
    \framepuzzle
    \fourwindscell{1}{2}{2}{}
    \fourwindscell{40}{40}{2}{}
  \end{fourwinds}
\end{document}
```

I also tried to use the `varwidth` package as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32773/minimize-automatically-the-page-size-of-the-pdf-outputs), but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

There is the `width` option for the `fourwinds` puzzle which needs to be set properly:

```
\begin{fourwinds}[rows=50,columns=50,width=750px,scale=0.5]
```