# Remove space after figure and before text

Tags: spacing, floats

I have a figure in my paper (I am using `IEEEtran` package). After this figure there exists a space between the figure and the text. How can I reduce the size of this white space. To be specific the space is between the caption of the figure and the text of my paper. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 67):

This depends on the location of the float - if the float is at the top of the page, the gap between the caption and the text is `\textfloatsep`, while the gap for a float in the middle of the page is given by `\intextsep`.

From the [`layouts` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/layouts) [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/layouts/layman.pdf) it is possible to see the lengths in terms of page/document float elements (p 21 onward):

[image]

Default for [`ieeetran`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran) are

- `\textfloatsep`: `1.7\baselineskip plus 0.2\baselineskip minus 0.5\baselineskip`
- `\intextsep`: `\baselineskip plus 0.2\baselineskip minus 0.2\baselineskip`

and therefore depends on the choice of the default font (since that sets `\baselineskip`). The default pt-form is therefore

- `\textfloatsep`: `20.4pt plus 2.4pt minus 4.8pt`
- `\intextsep`: `12.0pt plus 2.4pt minus 2.4pt`

in the `10pt` font size. The above includes some stretch/shrink. You can modify them using `\setlength`. For example,

```
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{\baselineskip plus 0.2\baselineskip minus 0.2\baselineskip}
```

would allow for between (roughly) `10pt` and `15pt` gap between the float and the text. Something like

```
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{5pt}
```

would fix the distance to `5pt` (without stretch/shrink).

Comment: I'm having a huge space between the end of a paragraph and the beginning of the next one, I don't know the reason, I'm using IEEE trans template

Comment: @user1460166: What do you have around these paragraphs? What float specifiers do you use for any floats around it?

Comment: I have a float after the end of the paragraph \begin{figure}[t]
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
  \node[mynode] (image2) 
  {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{avghist}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{}
\label{}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure*}[pht]
{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{squash3}}\caption{AA} 
\label{}
\end{figure*}
\begin{table*}[pht]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}>{\hsize=0.8\hsize}X *2{>{\hsize=1.1\hsize}X}@{}}
\toprule
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{AAA}
\label{}
\end{table*}

Comment: @user1460166: Do you really have 2 figures (nested)? It's difficult to gauge what else might be the problem.

Comment: I have two figures then a table

Comment: @user1460166: If that's it after the paragraph, how about trying to add `\raggedbottom` to your document. If you're using the `twocolumn` document option (which I'm guessing you are), the default is `\flushbottom`.

Comment: it worked but now instead of having couple of medium white spaces in this page I have one large white space, I think its something related to [H], but I can't figure out the solution

Comment: @user1460166: Yes, if you're using `[H]`, the it's actually not a float. However, you don't mention that in some of the code snippets you posted. I think you should [ask a new question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and give all the details necessary to solve the problem.

Comment: I've asked a new question found here if you could assist me, thanks http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125991/white-space-in-file

Comment: Can I change these parameter such as `\textfloatsep` onlyt locally in one section or from a certain point? I want to try to get some floats to fit together in my appendix but I don't want to affect the nice look of the main text.

Comment: @Kvothe: Yes, sure. I'd store the length, then change it, then restore it. You may have to leave about a page or so of leeway for the changes to have an effect, as the lengths are considered when building a page, so not immediately surrounding a float construction. Alternatively, if you want to keep certain figures *together*, you can put them in the same float. Yes, two `\includegraphics` with two `\caption`s in the same `figure` environment. Then you can space them out with `\vspace{\floatsep}` (or portions thereof). All kinds of possibilities. :)

Comment: Can the space between figure and its caption could be removed as well?

Comment: @alper: Adjustments like that can be done via the [`caption` package](//ctan.org/pkg/caption). For example, look at the length `abovecaptionskip` and `belowcaptionskip` in the [`caption` documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/caption).

Answer (score 31):

If you do not want to modify the standard template and just want a quick fix for this, you may add the following command to your document preamble:

`\newcommand{\squeezeup}{\vspace{-2.5mm}}`

Then, you can use the command `\squeezeup` throughout your document for reducing the free space after/before figures, formulas, etc., as needed.

Answer (score 20):

Werner's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60479/7710) is obviously a good one. However, I encountered a gotcha.

Using a setting like he suggested:

> `\setlength{\textfloatsep}{\baselineskip plus 0.2\baselineskip minus 0.5\baselineskip}`

produced a cryptic error:

> `Package calc Error: 'p' invalid at this point...0.2\baselineskip minus 0.5\baselineskip}`

After some playing around, I found out that it stumbles over the `plus ... minus` construction in combination with the `\baseline` command. What works is to multiply the lone `\baseline` by 1:

> `\setlength{\textfloatsep}{1\baselineskip plus 0.2\baselineskip minus 0.5\baselineskip}`

Using lengths like `5pt` instead of the baseline command is unproblematic.

Comment: Got me an extra paragraph or two in my paper :-)

Answer (score 8):

You can use `etoolbox` package. Just set a `\vskip` with a negative value at the start (`\BeforeBeginEnvironment` or `\AtBeginEnvironment`) and at the end (`\AfterEndEnvironment`) of the environment `figure`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{figure}{\vskip-2ex}
\AfterEndEnvironment{figure}{\vskip-1ex}

\begin{document}

  \lipsum[1]

  \begin{figure}[h]
    \includegraphics{your_figure}
    \caption{text}
  \end{figure}

  \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: If the float, well, _floats_ to another place, the `\vskip`s stay at the point of figure's declaration. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/493087/106612).

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, you can use `\vspace{-10mm}` in the figure code:

```
\begin{figure} 
    \centering
    \subfloat[\label{fig_2a}]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{Figures/Coss.eps}}
    \hfill
    \subfloat[\label{fig_2b}]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{Figures/Energy.pdf}}
    \\
    \caption{Nonlinear output capacitance characteristics of the MOSFETs  } \label{fig_2}
    \vspace{-10mm}%Put here to reduce too much white space after your table 
\end{figure}
```

Comment: It worked like a charm!