# Remove the unnecessary white space between figures and the sentences

Tags: spacing, floats

This is the command I used to have the figures.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{ch5}
    \caption{lalalalal}
    \label{llaa}               
\end{figure}
```

However, there will too much gap between the last sentence of the paragraph before the figure and the figure. How do I omit it?

Comment: Please always post a complete document that shows the problem (you can use the `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}` option so we don't need the actual figures. using `[h]` on its own is usually a bad idea latex essentially changes it to `[ht]`  Also ther eis a possibility that the space is inside the figure test this with `\fbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{ch5}} does the space come inside the box?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle No

Comment: well in that case the only space added above the figure is `\intextsep` but if the following text doesn't allow a good page break the whole page may be stretched if you have `\flushbottom` can't guess without an example.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  this is the example%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% theorem one says that \begin{figure}[h] \centering \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{ch5_2} \caption{vvv} \label{fd} \end{figure} \begin{flushleft} \textbf{Proof:} \end{flushleft}

Comment: No I meant edit the question to have a complete document, please see [these suggestions](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that#answer-3225)

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [Remove space after figure and before text](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60477/5764).