# \setlength not working

Tags: tables, spacing

I am having trouble with setting space before and after a table. Here is my code for a ten-column table:

```
\begin{tabular}{cccccccccc} 
\toprule
..
..
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

As you can see, it can't be any simpler. In my text body I've used 1.5 spacing and I want that to be the spacing between the text and the table above and below. However, `\setlength{\intextsep}{1.5pt}` doesn't do a thing no matter what size I choose, be it 1.5pt or 6pt.

The problem is partially solved by beginning with the command `\begin{tabular}[t]`, as the `[t]` part aligns the table with the text above, but the text below the document remains right below the bottom rule.

Answer (score 3):

`\intextsep` deals with the gap between a *float* within the text body and the rest of the text around it (see [Remove space after figure and before text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60477/5764)). Since you're using only a `tabular`, there is no *float*ing behaviour, hence the non-response from setting `\intextsep`.

If you wish to add some space above/below the non-floating `tabular`, do so using

```
\vspace{\baselineskip}
\begin{tabular}{...}
  ...
\end{tabular}
\vspace{\baselineskip}
```

where you adjust `\baselineskip` to suit your needs. You may even consider creating a new length (say) `\tabularsep` which you set in your preamble to a suitable length.

Of course, you could also wrap the `tabular` inside a `table` (which is a float) with an `[H]` specifier (provided by the [`float` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/float)) so that it could be treated like a regular `tabular`. That way an adjustment to `\intextsep` should work as expected.