# How to remove white blank space on top of the page in Lyx

Tags: spacing, floats, lyx, text

I am trying to remove a blank white space in lyx between text and Image using ert \vspace{-5cm} but it is not working.

Does anyone know how yo solve this problem?

I have tried using the below link to get my answer but still I did not manage:

[Remove space after figure and before text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60477/remove-space-after-figure-and-before-text?rq=1)

Comment: if the space is at the top of the page, an ordinary `\vspace` will disappear.  for that situation, use `\vspace*`.  if the space is elsewhere, we'll need a concrete example to make a diagnosis.

Comment: so i will do an ert juss \vspace*{-10cm} for example

Answer (score 4):

okay, try

```
\vspace*{-5cm}
* commands to go beyond cutline.
```

if this doesn't work. try to clear your page by using `\clearpage`.
if not move your top margin.

```
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-5cm}
```

if not please post your minimal work. ^_^

Comment: + Torbjorn T. - Thank you for your feedback with thee \clearpage is enough as worked.

Comment: In LyX `\vspace*` can be obtained with the "protected" checkbox in the vertical space dialog.

Comment: yeah it took a while for me to start using '\clearpage'  only when i had too many floats and only when i couldn't really figure out how not to make them line up. Yes i really managed without \clearpage for a while but after bunch of figures i was in a need of solution.