# How delete space between floats and text?

Tags: pdftex

My question is how I can squeeze space between picture and text(sections, subsections and normal text). Also I tried [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60477/remove-space-after-figure-and-before-text), but \vspace is not working well with measurements, sometimes it overlaps the text of another paragraph.

I show you how looks like with \vspace:

[image]
Furthermore, I tried \textfloatsep but is not working ...

My goal is make a three column document layout(triptych) with some pictures.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[margin=0.6cm]{geometry}

\newcommand{\squeezeup}[1]{\vspace{-#1}}

% \setlength{\textfloatsep}{10pt plus 1.0pt minus 2.0pt} %dont work

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

    \begin{multicols}{3}
        \section{section 1}
        \blindtext
        \section{section 2}

        \subsection{section 2.1}
        \blindtext        % \\[3mm]
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{place1.jpg}%\\[3mm]        

        \subsection{section 2.1}
        \blindtext        % \\[3mm]
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{place2.jpg}%\\[3mm]        
        % \squeezeup
        \vspace{-9mm} % don't work
        \subsection{section 2.1}        
        \squeezeup{0.5cm}        
        \blindtext
        % \\[3mm]
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{place3.jpg}%\\[3mm]        

        \subsection{section 2.3}        
        \blindtext
        % \\[3mm]
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{place4.jpg}%\\[3mm]        

        \subsection{section 1}
        \blindtext
        \enlargethispage{\baselineskip}

        % \\[3mm]
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{place5.png}%\\[3mm]        

        \subsection{section 1}
        \blindtext        % \\[3mm]
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{place6.jpg}%\\[3mm]        
        
        \subsection{section 1}
        \blindtext        % \\[3mm]
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{place7.jpg}%\\[3mm]        

    \end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the goal here. You want to have them all in one page? Usually, we don't want manfully adjust those spaces. Let latex do the format base on the contents, it will yield relative good typeset results.

Comment: you almost certainly never want to have `\vspace`  within a document (and definitely not negative space) but if you removed the `% \squeezeup` comment, leaving a blank line, the space would work at the point you expected.

Comment: The goal is is unclear but also the question. There are not floats in your code and floats should not be used with multicol. Maybe you will find of interest this [alternative approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73572/11604) to have a 3-column layout with figures.

Comment: Thank you Fran, flowgram package is exactly what I wanted.