# How to apply \looseness=-1 to ALL the paragraphs?

Tags: line-breaking, paragraphs

I'm writing a short  document of (3-4 pages), and try to condense it into the allowed space.

Putting `\looseness=-1` at the end a paragraph helps quite a lot. Is there a way to tell LaTeX to treat **every** paragraph as if there is a `\looseness=-1` at its end, or must I put the command after each and every paragraph by myself?

Comment: [Related question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/674/squeezing-scientific-paper-to-fit-within-page-limits).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

At the end? Rather at the beginning. And generally:

```
\everypar{\looseness=-1}
```

However it does not mean that every paragraph will be one line shorter.

Comment: Thanks! why at the beginning? I was always putting it at the end.

Comment: @RanG. Just a save way. At the beginning you are sure, which one is the current paragraph.

Comment: using `\everypar` in this manner might very well overrule some "desirable" settings established in basic latex and various document classes and packages.  for example, check its effect in itemized and enumerated lists.  (i haven't tried it, but a quick scan of `latex.ltx` shows that `\everypar` is used extensively.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton You a right, but OP has very short document, where he/she want put as much, as it is possible. I wouldn't set the general rules in such a way, but if OP wants to try...

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke -- on a very short, text only, document, worth a try.  just be aware that there may be side effects.

Comment: Slightly safer is `\everypar=\expandafter{\the\everypar\loosness=-1 }`. One can put it at the end of each paragraph by redefining `\par`, but LaTeX also uses `\par` very extensively. Finally, one can simply set `\linepenalty=1000` (or larger). This adds a penalty for each line and so TeX tries to reduce the number of lines. It is not reset with each paragraph, so it only needs to be set once. Basic LaTeX does not touch `\linepenalty` except to set the default value (`10`).

Answer (score 9):

Dan's suggestion in a comment to Przemysław Scherwentke's answer deserves more visibility:

> Finally, one can simply set `\linepenalty=1000` (or larger). This adds a penalty for each line and so TeX tries to reduce the number of lines. It is not reset with each paragraph, so it only needs to be set once. Basic LaTeX does not touch `\linepenalty` except to set the default value (`10`).