# \expandafter \the\everypar - undefined control sequence

Tags: expansion

From [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146890/how-to-apply-looseness-1-to-all-the-paragraphs#comment333325_146893), I got this snippet:

```
\everypar=\expandafter{\the\everypar\loosness=-1 }
```

However, this produces this error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<everypar> ...ubpenalty \everypar {}\fi \loosness
=-1
```

Why? What does it mean? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `\looseness` with an `e` not `\loosness`