# \everypar{\looseness=-1} removes space before section title and only for section

Tags: formatting

I tried to use this ([via](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/146893/2272)):

```
\everypar{\looseness=-1}
```

However, I'm not exactly sure where to put it. If I put it somewhere before `\begin{document}`, it doesn't seem to have any effect. If I put it after some `\section{}`, it has an effect but it removes all the space up to the title of the following section, and it seems to apply only for the current section.

Is that expected? I want that it is applied to the whole document. And I don't want to alter the space before section titles.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You probably want to increase `\linepenalty` from its default value of 10 to, say, 200. This way, long paragraphs will tend to use less lines.

Comment: As @egreg suggests , If the real question is "how do I force latex to use a more compact setting to reduce the page count" then that's a reasonable question but it's a different question to this one.

Comment: Yes I know, but I guess [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/674/squeezing-scientific-paper-to-fit-within-page-limits) would be the relevant then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need

```
\everypar{\looseness=-1 }
```

with a space to terminate the number, otherwise if the paragraph started with 3 `\looseness` would be set to -13...

Are you sure that you want to apply it to a whole document? It really isn't designed to be used that way, it is designed for final tweaks of page/line breaking (there are other better ways of trying to force a compact setting if that is the intention).

Also you can not set `\everypar` in LaTeX without taking note of the current setting, after headings and in lists latex is using `\everypar` to control indentation, or insert the list label etc.

that is why the comments on the referenced answer suggest

```
\everypar\expandafter{\the\everypar\looseness=-1 }
```

To re-insert the previous value of `\everypar`, however this is still likely to break something. Setting `\looseness` automatically to a fixed non-zero value just isn't really anything that should be supported.

Comment: I tried with the space but that doesn't change anything for me. The space before the next section title is still removed.

Comment: @Albert yes as I say you can not just over-write `\everypar` discarding its previous value as that will remove spaces, item labels, paragraph shape settings and anything else latex had set in `\everypar`.

Comment: @Albert see the comments on the answer that you quote. Barbara was using understatement by "may be side effects" she means "this will destroy your document settings"

Comment: @Albert that is why there is a suggestion to use `\expandafter{\the\everypar` to re-insert the previous value, I updated the answer a bit.

Comment: Ah, it sounds like you said that `\everypar{\looseness=-1 }` with the space should work to terminate the number, but it does not.

Comment: @Albert It does terminate the number.