# How to make the vertical rubber space between paragraphs as compact as possible?

Tags: paragraphs, vertical-spacing

I am setting a document in 2 columns via the `multicol`-package. It is a newspaper-like document.

How can I force LaTeX to–ideally–remove as much extra-added vertical rubber space, which is used to make "consistent" looking line breaks and vertical spacing between paragraphs on one page?

All the while that spacing might look alright and good for that one section, it seems to be noticeably different in other sections. This is somewhat... meh. Not the best look, honestly.

So far I only found [this code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146890/how-to-apply-looseness-1-to-all-the-paragraphs/332810#332810):

```
\everypar=\expandafter{\the\everypar\loosness=-1}
\linepenalty=1000
```

(Note: I am aware that it is literally impossible sometimes unless I were to use floats, but they are super tricky–if not impossible–to use in multicol-environments... I think (based on reading threads right here on TeX.sx. So I would just like to *try* something else regardless.)

## MWE

```
\documentclass[
11pt,
a4paper,
false-,
]
{scrartcl}

\usepackage{
lmodern,
multicol,
blindtext,
mdframed,
}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\listfiles

\begin{document}
\begin{center}\huge
Title stuff
\end{center}

\begin{multicols*}{2}
\section{Word}

There really are some words.
And then some.
AAaaaa bbbb cccc.

Now here is something interesting: {asdf}.

\blindtext[1]

\begin{center}
\rule{\columnwidth}{10pt}
\end{center}

Some words to form a sentence.
There really are some words.
And then some.

%\addvspace{2ex}%
There really are some words.
And then some.

\begin{center}\color{DarkBlue}
\rule{\columnwidth}{10pt}
\end{center}

\blindtext[1]

\everypar=\expandafter{\the\everypar\loosness=-1}
\linepenalty=1000

\begin{center}
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\columnwidth}
1 - Some stuff.
Words and such.
There really are some words.
And then some.

There really are some words.
And then some.
\end{minipage}
}
\end{center}

\blindtext[1]

\begin{center}
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\columnwidth}
2 - Some stuff.
Words and such.
%There really are some words.
%And then some.

There really are some words.
And then some.
\end{minipage}
}
\end{center}

\blindtext[1]

\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

## Screenshots of MWE

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi! Not sure what you want to change. `center` environment adds vertical spaces, maybe you can try to use `\par{\centering "whatever"\par}` instead?

Comment: Try `\raggedbottom`. `The default `\flushbottom` makes all pages/columns end at the same vertical position on the typeset page by adjusting the vertical space between paragraphs, etc. `\raggedbottom` makes no changes to the vertical spacing.

Comment: what do you want `\everypar=\expandafter{\the\everypar\loosness=-1}` to do???  it is ... unusual code but it affects line breaking not the inter-paragraph space taht is the subject of your question.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I hoped it would help.

Comment: it has no effect on inter-paragraph space at all

Comment: Sometimes it's more effective to *add* a line to a paragraph to optimize the number of lines in a column.  In that case, `\looseness=1` is what you want, not `-1`.  This is very hard (if not nearly impossible) to decide automatically.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell you are mainly asking about space above and below `center` which is `\partopsep` if it is between paragraphs or `\topsep` otherwise. Setting this to 0pt produces

[image]

```
\documentclass[
11pt,
a4paper,
%%%% ? false-,
]
{scrartcl}

\setlength\partopsep{0pt}
\setlength\topsep{0pt}

\usepackage{
lmodern,
multicol,
blindtext,
mdframed,
}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% not needed unless your latex is old \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\listfiles

\begin{document}
\begin{center}\huge
Title stuff
\end{center}

\begin{multicols*}{2}
\section{Word}

There really are some words.
And then some.
AAaaaa bbbb cccc.

Now here is something interesting: {asdf}.

\blindtext[1]

\begin{center}
\rule{\columnwidth}{10pt}
\end{center}

Some words to form a sentence.
There really are some words.
And then some.

%\addvspace{2ex}%
There really are some words.
And then some.

\begin{center}\color{DarkBlue}
\rule{\columnwidth}{10pt}
\end{center}

\blindtext[1]

% commented out as it is too weird
%\everypar=\expandafter{\the\everypar\loosness=-1}
%\linepenalty=1000

\begin{center}
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\columnwidth}
1 - Some stuff.
Words and such.
There really are some words.
And then some.

There really are some words.
And then some.
\end{minipage}
}
\end{center}

\blindtext[1]

\begin{center}
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\columnwidth}
2 - Some stuff.
Words and such.
%There really are some words.
%And then some.

There really are some words.
And then some.
\end{minipage}
}
\end{center}

\blindtext[1]

\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not only this particular environment. The global document option was missing `parskip=` before the `false-`. Sorry about that. I think I should delete my question and try to rework it. The underlying issue (not really a "problem" per se) is real, it's just... I can't for the life of me figure out how to create an MWE which reproduces some kind of magical vertical rubber spacing between paragraphs. I do not use `setstretch`. There is `\singlespacing` right before `\begin{document}`. Hm.

Comment: @henry if you have stretchy space between paragraphs (and flushbottom in effect) the paragraph space will stretch if the page is short and that will be because there is a large unbreakbale box at the top of the next page.