# Squeezing a paper into a page limit - with IEEEtran

Tags: spacing, page-breaking, ieeetran

I'm working on this draft for a submission to some conference which - woe is me - uses [IEEEtran](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/). I could rant about that class for days, but never mind right now... the point is, I need to squeeze about 8.475 pages into 8 (ignoring references which don't count of course). I have already gone to some pains to rephrase my text, to make it less verbose, to avoid unessential comments, etc. Now, if push comes to shove I'll do some serious re-editing and eventually resign myself to cut some content, but obviously I want to avoid that - so I want to try to squeeze space some.

I've read the general version of this question:

[Squeezing scientific paper to fit within page limits](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/674/squeezing-scientific-paper-to-fit-within-page-limits)

and I already use:

```
\usepackage[subtle]{savetrees}
\usepackage{microtype} 
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{caption}
\addtolength{\parindent}{-1mm}
```

which is pretty tame.

I need to get a bit more violent... so,

- In the general case you can't touch anything which the class might be imposing. With IEEEtran, maybe there's some tolerance for some fiddling with some values?
- The use of `\usepackage[moderate]{savetrees}` helps, but it give me hideous spacing between elements on some pages. Can I disable the "keep lines on same page" feature for a specific paragraph as an ugly way around this phenomenon?
- I think maybe I can get away with reducing space around figures, and between figures and their captions. How do I that (and not be considered an IEEEtrans criminal)?
- What do you think might be the most helpful in this situation?
- Can I squeeze horizontal spacing between glyphs, or words, a bit more?

**Notes:**

- Please, no lecturing about improving grammar and writing less. If it helps you, suppose after I've done that they go and change the number of pages from 8 to 7 :-)
- I have multiple figures, but almost no equations.

Comment: apply some editorial changes to the words?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: For shaving off an extra line from a paragraph here -and-there? I need stronger medicine, doc.

Comment: compared to impairing readability by squeezing interword space, it must always be preferable to consider rephrasing the text with less words.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Fewer words.

Comment: @cfr fewer words and gooder grammer!

Comment: Why do you think that you can get away with doctoring the output, given that you are required to use that class? Apart from issues of legibility, what makes you think this will still comply? (Can you really use `savetrees` with a journal/conference class and get away with it?) More generally, this is why specifying length limits in terms of page count is ridiculous.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle For the very bestest results.

Comment: @cfr: 1. I was asking specifically about the extent to which I can doctor. 2. IEEEtran looks exceedingly ugly anyway; suprisingly, savetrees doesn't hurt the appearance much... 3. When I organize a conference, I won't have that.

Comment: 1. Then the question is off-topic here and should be asked on academia se, perhaps. 2. That isn't really the point: journals and conferences have standard styles and expect all papers to use them. Whether their choices are typographically well-judged or not is a different matter.

Comment: Did you read the comments on the question you linked? E.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/674/squeezing-scientific-paper-to-fit-within-page-limits#comment758_674. The answers there are explicitly addressing a situation in which only the margins are standard - the document class etc. is left to the author's choice. (And `savetrees` violates that single constraint by changing the margins anyway.)

Comment: @cfr: `savetrees` doesn't change the margins with `subtle` or `moderate`. Anyway, I've gone down to `subtle` after gaining a bit from playing with some float separator lengths.

Comment: Use `ieeeconf` from the conference website. IEEE conference mode is simply ugly and weird. Many dropped its usage some time ago.

Comment: @percusse: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. You're saying I can replace IEEEtran with something else? Or I you saying that the something-else (ieeeconf document class) is something I should _avoid_?

Comment: Sorry. I meant: the conference mode of `ieeetran` is almost never used anymore. Instead you can find the `ieeeconf` document class which is usually recommended by the conference author kits. Especially paperplaza (or papercept) links should provide it.

Comment: @percusse: The conference CFP directed me [here](http://www.ieee.org/conferences_events/conferences/publishing/templates.html) ... I can't just use another doc class (and it's too late to start inquiring about that now.)

Comment: Look fpr the submission page not CFP or [Use this page](http://css.paperplaza.net/conferences/support/tex.php). And it cannot be late as it is just a one line change. Also if you squeeze too much the editor will ask you to trim off anyways. So you can't get away with zipping the contents in a page. Trust me I've published more than enough papers on IEEE conferences.

Comment: Well, I'll try creating two versions and tell the organizers I have a "nicer-looking" one.

Comment: Is there any news here?

Comment: @Johannes_B: Yes and no. Will add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation](http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/macros/latex/contrib/savetrees/savetrees.pdf) of the savetrees package, you'll find that each one of the basic levels it offers (subtle, moderate, extreme) is actually several (independent?) options that you can switch on or off.

For example, for `subtle`, you have:

- `bibbreaks` - Allow page breaks within bibliographic entries.
- `paragraphs` - Discourage TeX from allowing the last line of a paragraph to contain only a single word.
- `floats` - Relax float placement (more floats per page, increased ability to share pages with text, etc.).
- `mathspacing` - Reduce the amount of space within mathematical expressions.
- `wordspacing` - Reduce the amount of space between words.
- `tracking` - Reduce the amount of space between characters.

and additional options for the stronger levels.

Now, for each of these the documentation gives a bird's-eye view of how it's achieved. So you can:

- Mix and match options you like or you find appropriate.
- (Harder) replicate some of the relevant code of savetrees to have the same effect but to a weaker degree when you don't like their defaults.